# menu inside views page

Tags: views, routes

I was wondering if this is possible. I have a views which is displayed as a page and I want to have menu inside that page. Is there a module available to achieve this?

Here's a picture of what I want to copy:

[image: menu]

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm a newbie

Comment: It is commonly done with a view attachment or block if you are creating the menu from the view as well. Otherwise add the menu as a block with visibility set to the path of the view.

Comment: To add to J. Reynolds comment, check out the module called [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, install it then create  a block of your menu you want, then with attachment feature of views,add it(your block) to your views(as attachment) and enjoy :).

Comment: hi, i don't know if i did it correctly but i think it worked well the way i want it. thanks for the tip on using menu block. cheers :)

Comment: @user3682259 your welcome, try to do it. you can :)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to place a menu in side bar use [Menu Block Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block).When  user clicks on a menu item, it will load the page linked to that menu item.

But If you want to provide filter criteria in side bar, like if user clicks on "Koryo", It will filter the results and display results of "Koryo" only, than you should consider [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi).